# Find label for checkbox with CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-selectors

I'm trying to change the standard checkboxes to a font-awsome version.
The problem is I can't change the HTML since it's generated and I can't use jQuery either.
Is there a way to "find" the label for my checkbox in the html below and change label:before on checkbox true or false?

EDIT: I think I might have been a bit unclear, the full code includes a javascript that makes it impossible for me to use javascript without changing it.
Also, the class for the labeltext is commonly used and can be -1 or -2 as well.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="odincategory odincategory38 odincategory-even odincategory-placement2 odincategory-placement-even odincategory-multi" id="odincategory38-holder">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="odincategorycheckcolumn">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odinanswer1" value="38" class="odincategorycheckmulti" id="odincategory38">
      </td>
      <td class="odincategorylabelcolumn">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="odincategorylabel38">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="odincategorylabel">
                <label for="odincategory38"><span class="odinfontnumber-0">Choice<br>
                  </span></label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="odincategorymarkcolumn"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I appreciate that it is generated, but, do you know the classes of the labels or any containers before it is generated?

Comment: the only way I can think of would be using javascript, ajax, etc. what are you trying to use the checkbox for? and why are you using a table within a table?

Comment: @NoLiver92 what the hell does AJAX have to do with it? Are you just throwing words that you think are related?

Comment: @NoLiver92 literally everything you just said is not related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done using pure CSS.
The problem is that you can only select adjacent, following or descending elements. In your case the label is somewhere else in the document tree.
If you could have the label next to the checkbox you could do something like

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  color: green;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

But this does not work with your code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this sample that change the color of the label...
In the same way you can change what you need.

In this example I used a button but you can write a special function that changes the font after page is loaded

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="odincategory odincategory38 odincategory-even odincategory-placement2 odincategory-placement-even odincategory-multi" id="odincategory38-holder">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="odincategorycheckcolumn">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odinanswer1" value="38" class="odincategorycheckmulti" id="odincategory38">
      </td>
      <td class="odincategorylabelcolumn">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="odincategorylabel38">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="odincategorylabel">
                <label for="odincategory38" id="labelForodincategory38"><span class="odinfontnumber-0">Choice<br>
                  </span></label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="odincategorymarkcolumn"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('labelForodincategory38').style.color='blue'" value="Click Me to Change Color" />
```